# How to enable ibus in loki 0.4.1

Tags: ibus

I installed ibus but not able use the keyboard.
Hindi typing booster is not working.

Intalled m17n and ibus table but by default its using in built keyboard layout.

Answer (score -1):

Run `ibus-daemon -drx` in terminal.